# Class reflection from a static method

Tags: actionscript-3, class, reflection, static

I am using the excellent [org.as3commons.reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/asdoc/index.html) and [org.as3commons.lang](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/asdoc/index.html) libraries and have hit a snag.  I have a static method in one of my classes that needs to do reflection on *its* class.  The reflect library has a Type.forClass(clazz:Class) static method that clearly requires a Class variable.  There is no **this** keyword allowed in static methods/code so now I need to know if there is a way to get the class for which my static method is being called.

I need something that will work in the non-debug version of Flash player, so any Error.getStackTrace() tricks won't work.  Too bad no stack trace is available in the normal VM.

```
import org.as3commons.lang.ClassUtils;
import org.as3commons.reflect.Type;

protected static function doReflection(): void
{
  var aClass: Class = ClassUtils.forInstance(this); // this not allowed in static methods
  var ct: Type = Type.forClass(aClass);
  // do stuff with type
}
```

I gave up searching on Google and other sites; always ended up getting tutorials and tips on everything related to static members, performance issues, *everything* except what I am looking for.

Overall, I want to cache a bunch of things about the class in static members to save unnecessary work each time the class gets instantiated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about passing a reference to the instance you need as an argument of static method?

Comment: The static method is called on first instantiation of the class, something like protected static var _classInitialized: Boolean = init(); Ok, so the code will become something like "all instances check if the class has been initialized, and if not, call the protected static function init(this)". Was hoping for a more direct approach, but that'll work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might not work in all situations...mainly will depend on what happens on your constructor.

```
import org.as3commons.lang.ClassUtils;
import org.as3commons.reflect.Type;

static private const CLASS:Object = new YourReflectedClass;

protected static function doReflection(): void {

 // var aClass: Class = ClassUtils.forInstance(this); // this not allowed in static methods

  var aClass:Class = CLASS.constructor;

  var ct: Type = Type.forClass(aClass);
  // do stuff with type
}
```

A better approach would be to use:

```
static private const CLASS:Class = YourReflectedClass;
var ct: Type = Type.forClass(CLASS);
```

Just wanted to show you the Object.constructor method...

Comment: Nice method, that Object.constructor thing, although the problem is finding the class itself if there is no instance; I know that class A is class A in its definition, but not if class B subclasses class A.  Another problem that I noticed soon after writing this question is that as3 is weird when it comes to inheritance of static members, so I don't know if any of this will work at all for my purposes; I might be running into a wall. Specifically, are static vars in class A unique for class B & C?  Very hard to find definitive documentation on the subject; I am still digging.

Comment: @ Alan G. a little research of static var inheritance: http://wonderfl.net/c/lLor

Comment: @ www0z0k Thanks, that's an interesting demo.

Answer (score 1):

i think in debug-mode you can use the stack-trace of an error object to retrieve/reflect the class from static context, but in release build you have to get the global scope to reflect:

```
//RELEASE BUILD
public static function whoAmI():void
{    
    var clsName:String = describeType((function m():*{return this})()).constant.@type;
    var cls:Class = getDefinitionByName(clsName) as Class;
}

//DEBUG MODE (getStackTrace()-hack)
public static function whoAmI():void
{    
    var stack:Array = new Error().getStackTrace().replace("Error\n","").split("\n");
    //write your stack-trace parser here
    var clsName:String = ...
    var cls:Class = getDefinitionByName(clsName) as Class;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
protected static function doReflection(): void
{
    var aClass: Class = ClassThatYouAreIn as Class; 
    var ct: Type = Type.forClass(aClass);
    // do stuff with type
}
```

as static methods are even not inherited...

Edit: OK, I just saw that this was already proposed...